Trying to play with Pictureboxes Image loading on Winforms C#
So I'm building a text based adventure like zork, but I'm adding my own UI to illustrate backgrounds kind of like the Oregon Trail. A problem I'm running into on my designer.cs is that my Properties doesn't exist.
Background.Image = Dawnbarrow.Properties.Resources._11;
Background.Location = new Point(0, 0);
Background.Name = "Background";
Background.Size = new Size(952, 298);
Background.TabIndex = 8;
Background.TabStop = false;
Background.Click += Background_Click;

In the GUI on the designer, I'm having trouble first setting the image from a resource file instead of a local file. THEN, I'm having trouble manipulating the image once I have finished importing the file. (changing the file to something completely separate)
I can manage to import a local file but then the identity of the image changes to something I don't know how to locate the origin of. This one works without problem though.
Background.Image = (Image)resources.GetObject("Background.Image");
I tried to load my image using the GUI on the properties tab of a winforms picturebox, and from there I wanted to manipulate the image.
I feel like I did all the right steps, but I still somehow have an error thrown on the "Properties does not exist" front.
Secondly, I don't know the syntax for how to update the image dynamically, I'm sure it's just a conditional statement that when true sets the file path to this etc.

Do you have a Resources.resx file?  What does it look like?
Maybe do a complete clean and rebuild?
You can change the image dynamically by just setting the Backbround.Image.

Are you changing the Persistence to Embedded?
